# data table cell math

Tags: c#, datatable

I am very new to the whole thing of C# and would tremendously appreciate your wisdom on this:
I am making a game-like thing that needs to store and constantly update a database for a population of people.

Currently I am trying to create a `DataTable dt;`

Add columns `dt.Colums.Add("age", typeof(int));`

Add rows `dt.Rows.Add(10);`

Now I would like to dynamically adjust the content of the cell which holds the age int value of 10 to 11.

I try to `dt.Rows[0]["age"] += 1;`

However, I get the following:

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am rather confused on why the "cell" returns an object rather than an int. How would it be possible to do math operations directly with the contents of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexer for `DataRow` returns an `object`, even if you set the data type of the column. You can either cast the value to `int`:

```
dt.Rows[0]["age"] = (int)(dt.Rows[0]["age"]) + 1;
```

or use the `Field` extension method

```
dt.Rows[0]["age"] = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("age") + 1;
```

Note that `+=` will not work in either case since you have to use an expression (either a cast or a method call) to get the value out.

Comment: Thank you! The cast solution worked for me! I saw solutions with field and covert methods; however, I had an issue with these not being recognized in that context. Perhaps, it is issue of unity, which is something I should have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Here dt.Rows[0]["age"] is an object and not Integer type so Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'
Try this,

```
        dt.Rows[0]["age"] = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0]["age"]) + 1;
```